# Entity Framework use function from other repository

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 application for a store. The application is already built, but I have to add some features.

The application uses an domain layer with interfaces and Entity Framework.

There is a database table `Products`, and I created a table `Reviews`. The tables are linked by `ProductId <> ReviewId` and have a one-to-many relationship.

`Products`:

- ProductId
- ProductName
- ProductPrice

`Review`:

- ReviewId
- ReviewName
- ReviewRating
- ReviewText

I have created a new Entity framework `ReviewRepository` with a function:

```
getAverageForProduct(int ProductId)
```

which calculates the average review rating.

```
    public double GetReviewAverage(int ProductId)
    {
        if (context.Review.Count(x => x.Product.ProductId == ProductId) == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return Math.Round(context.Review.Where(x => x.Product.ProductId == ProductId).Average(x => x.ReviewRating), 0);
        }
    }
```

Now I want to show the average rating on the product page.

The view is set up like this:

```
    @model IEnumerable<Domain.Entities.Products>
```

The products are show with the following loop:

```
    @foreach (var m in Model)
    {
    }
```

How can I calculate the average review rating for every product? This is because the view uses the `ProductRepository` from the controller (function: `getAllProducts()`), not the `ReviewRepository`.

The application does not use view models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem. Created a simple view model.

The Viewmodel:

```
public class PopularProductList
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public double Average { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller:

```
        var model = new List<PopularProductList>();

        foreach (var p in ProductRepository.GetPopularProducts())
        {
            var ProductList = new PopularProductList();
            ProductList.Product = p;
            ProductList.Average = ReviewRepository.GetReviewAverage(p.ProductId);

            model.Add(ProductList);
        }

        return View("Index", model);
```